# How to use POST API for sign up using python

Tags: python, post

I supposed to get a user data from a sign up form to the python using json and also connect it to mysql. So , this is the example i browse but i didnt get it. Can anybody help me with this please with clear explaination/examples.

```
import requests

base_url="www.google.com"
final_url="/{0}/friendly/{1}/url".format(base_url,3)

payload = {'number': 2, 'value': 1}
response = requests.post(final_url, data=payload)

print(response.text) #TEXT/HTML
print(response.status_code, response.reason) #HTTP
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to narrow down what you are asking?

Comment: i want to know how to capture data from the user in certain websites using json and API .